# Excel VBA Save path/name from cells with variables

Tags: vba, excel

I am using cells as the file path and filename to save a copy of my workbook.

Here's the code am using now but it puts spaces in between each cell.
Note only the ActiveSheet.Range cells will have the possibility of being blank

```
Dim NewWb As Workbook
sFile = Control_Sheet_VB.Range("H2") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("H8") & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E10") & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("D14") & " - Ticket #" & Control_Sheet_VB.Range("B2") & Control_Sheet_VB.Range("C2") & ".xlsm"
Set OldWb = ActiveWorkbook
OldWb.SaveCopyAs sFile
Set NewWb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
```

How can I make it so if some of the cells that are used as the file name are blank then it dose not put the extra space in the filename

Comment: Does surrounding each reference with e.g. `Trim(ActiveSheet.Range("H8"))` solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may go like this:

```
sFile = Control_Sheet_VB.Range("H2") & "\" & _
        IIf(ActiveSheet.Range("H8") <> "", ActiveSheet.Range("H8") & " ", "") & _
        IIf(ActiveSheet.Range("E10") <> "", ActiveSheet.Range("E10") & " ", "") & _
        IIf(ActiveSheet.Range("D14") <> "", ActiveSheet.Range("D14") & " ", "") & _
        " - Ticket #" & Control_Sheet_VB.Range("B2") & _
        Control_Sheet_VB.Range("C2") & ".xlsm"
```